# Angular2 app won't load in Plunker

Tags: angular, plunker

Pop quiz! I built an Anguar2 example in Plunker mirroring a routing problem that I am facing so that I could post the question to StackOverflow, but I can't get the darn thing to run in Plunker. The index page loads without errors, but my app component never renders on the page. I'll give you bragging rights if you can spot my configuration problem so I can post my real question. Thanks in advance.

Here is my example http://plnkr.co/edit/2imWa2?p=preview

All the code is in Plunker. This is the config file I took from this working Angular 2 example (http://plnkr.co/edit/FNBFPE?p=preview) to try to set-up the app, but I don't think it plays well with my set-up.

```
System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {
     app: "./src"
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: 'src/app.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another template https://plnkr.co/edit/NIbxKB?p=preview I don't know if this is what you want but this way it's working.

Here is also a Plunker that is from an Angular team member http://plnkr.co/edit/mk8wPfoqS66Qsuu2yN4F?p=preview. It shows how you can provide `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` globally.

```
bootstrap(App, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi: true})
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Thanks, Günter. That did it. That change, along with reformating my RouteLinks solved everything. Except for a WebPack issue. That is a topic for another day. Here is the working http://plnkr.co/edit/2imWa2?p=preview.

Comment: The question I was going to post was why my route links weren't working when trying load a completely different component on the page (equivalent to window.location). The fix to that that moving ROUTE_PROVIDERS, and FORM_PROVIDER to app.ts. I have not tried moving ROUTER_DIRECTIVES to app.ts. I'll do that today just to make our components a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You should bootstrap your application this way:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

import {App} from './app';

bootstrap(App, [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ]);
```

See this plunkr forked from your own one: http://plnkr.co/edit/QOwTLC?p=preview